# Transform 2D coordinates to respective index of in a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, coordinates

I'm programming a tic tac toe game and the way I manage the state of each cell is through an array like this:

```
cell_states = [
  [-1, -1, -1],
  [-1, -1, -1],
  [-1, -1, -1]
]
```

However, each cell in my game has a window coordinate `(x, y)`, where `(0, 0)` is the bottom left corner. How can I program a function such that it returns the index of a 2D array based on a coordinate input? Something like this is what I'm thinking of:

```
index = coords_to_index(x=0, y=0) #(0, 0) should be at the bottom left corner.
print(index) #prints (2, 0), the geometrically corresponding index. This is the part I'm struggling with.
```

Any suggestions on how to do this? Even better ways to manage cell states are welcome suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Why can’t you consider the coordinates in the window to be directly mapped to the element at that index?

Comment: I'm not the most experienced programmer, so I don't quite understand what you mean. Please elaborate (it's my fault, not yours). Do you mean I could use a dictionary in which the keys are the window coordinates and the state is the vale?

Comment: Don’t worry! :) What I meant is why not have coordinate (0, 0) in the game window at the list index [0][0]? Yes, it makes the list look upside down when printed, but it should work just fine.

Comment: Ah, yes! I didn't think of that! Manipulating the game window to my desire was not on my mind. Thank you! I'll do that.

Comment: What do you mean by _manipulating the game window to my desire was not on my mind_?

Comment: I interpreted your 2nd comment as having my indices equal to my coordinates. I could manipulate the game viewport such that the player only views, say, coordinates [0, 3] rather than what I have now, [0, 600].

Comment: On rereading your post, what do are you using the 2D list for? Why do you need the “geometrical equivalent”?

Comment: I've decided my original method was quite inefficient. I've opted to use a dictionary to store cell coordinates as keys and their states as the respective values. Your suggestions inspired the idea though.

Comment: A 2D list shouldn’t be less efficient for this kind of data, no? Using a dictionary makes a whole bunch of operations far more difficult.

Comment: To answer your question, picture a 3x3 grid. In my original post, I wanted each "cell" to correspond to each value in the list. For example, index [2][0] is at the bottom left corner of the array formatted above and in the game window as well. My issue comes when I need to map these array values onto coordinates on the screen. Rather than do that, I decided to use a dictionary in which there was no indexing required and the real coordinate values could be mapped to a "state" the cell was in (-1 or 1).

Comment: Isn’t what I proposed earlier fine? Can’t you have the state for coordinate (0, 0) at index [0][0]?

Comment: Yes, as stated in my third comment, I'm changing to your method, it's simpler.

Comment: I’m confused, aren’t you using a dictionary instead? That’s different, and can be quite restrictive.

Comment: I originally wanted to use a dictionary because I interpreted your 1st comment incorrectly. Now I'm going to do what you really meant. That is, having coord(0, 0) at index [0][0]

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Let me know if it works :)

Comment: Yes, I have successfully implemented your idea! Thanks for the help!